# Jquery ui datepicker css issues

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm unable to get the styles from the jquery UI in to a datepicker, the datepicker is displaying but without the relavent styling. I have added the relevant css files, here's the html file for the datepicker

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demos.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p> When?
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


<div class="demo-description">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Check the browser's console to see if anything isn't loading. Or try loading the CSS from a CDN.

Comment: Did you fix your un-closed <p> tag? That could be it also.

Answer (score 0):

I think your fault lies with not defining type="text/css" in your css link. Since your doctype doesn't specify html5 it could be causing issues.

type="css/text" is required in older versions of html.

Side note: It looks like you're missing a paragraph closing tag.

Comment: I've made the recommended changes but still it's not picking up the styling.

Comment: Can you link it? It's hard to tell much without seeing it.